# Trigger one event for one keyPress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keyboard-events

I'm trying to find a way to trigger an event just when a key has been pressed and not while it' s pressed. So i'm doing something like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 102) {
    bool = true;    
  }
});
```

and then in a handleEvents **setTimeout** :

```
if (bool){
        //do thing just one time
    }
```

Comment: Use `keydown` or `keyup` events.

Answer (score 1):

use `keydown` instead of `keypress` .

You have the following order chronologically :

- key down  key press  key up

```js
$(document).keypress(()=> console.log('I am keypress'))
$(document).keydown(()=> console.log('I am keydown'))
$(document).keyup(()=> console.log('I am keyup'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Press any key</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a singleton type event (the event handler only runs once), you can use the jQuery function `.one()`. This will automatically unbind the event handler after it has run once. Example:

```
$(document).one('keyup', function(event){
  if (event.keycode === 102){
    // code...
  }
});
```

*Note that using this on a keypress type event doesn't seem advisable since the handler will be unbound the first run through regardless of whether or not the correct key was pressed.

It sounds like you want you event handler to run only once the user has finished pressing the key. Like the other comments, I suggest using either the `'keydown'` or `'keyup'` event.